# Angular JS, importing some specifics data from a JSON file

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I’m trying to make an angular JS app that displays notes. 
All the notes are stored in a note.json file and the main page of the app shows just fews fields of all the notes.
I would like to add the feature that open a new page if I click on a particular note.
The new page should displays all the data referred to the clicked note.

I have a show.html file which is the template of the note selected, and a notes-show-controller.js  which, when I click a note on the main page, should import just some specific data from the note.json file.
Here the code of the two file:

show.html

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
<p>{{note.title}}</p>
<p>Created By: {{note.user}}</p>

<p>Description:</p>
<p>{{note.description}}</p>

<p>Contents:</p>
<p>{{note.content}}</p>
</div>
```

notes-show-controller.js

```
angular.module('NotesApp').controller('NotesShowController', function($http, $routeParams) {
var controller = this;
controller.notes = [];


$http.get('notes/'+ $routeParams.id).success(function(data){                    
    controller.notes = data;
})
});
```

My question is: is it possible to import from the json file, which is an array of object, just few fields of a particular object? and if not, how can I solve my problem?
Here is the notes.json file

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "users":"Fabio",
    "title":"questa è la prima nota",
    "description": "blablablablablablablabla",
    "content":"èoisèdoifjèosijdfèosjdfèoijsèdofij"
},
{
    "id": 2,        
    "users":"Francesco",        
    "title":"questa è la seconda nota",
    "description": "huhuhuuhuhuhuhuuhuuhuhuh",
    "content":"èoisèdoifjèosijdfèosjdfèoijsèdofij"
},
{
    "id": 3,        
    "users":"Fernando",             
    "title":"questa è la terza nota",
    "description": "cicicicicicicicicicicici",
    "content":"èoisèdoifjèosijdfèosjdfèoijsèdofij"
}
]
```

If it help to solve my problem, I've also made a Plunker file that shows all the app,  here is the link:

[Plunker File](http://plnkr.co/edit/QcxT3Ht1N81N3T69rgiz?p=preview)

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me.

Comment: Anyway you will have to read all the json file. So retrieve all the json and then filter on what you need

Comment: How can I filter the json file importing just what I need? Can you make me an example?

Comment: filter based on what criteria? It's not hard to search how to use angular filter or how to filter an array yourself

Comment: @DanieleMartini Inside your success function just take what you need and that's all

Comment: Ok I'll try to do it searching by myself. I just wanted an help because I'm not very familiar whit ajax and json but doesn't matter. I really don't know why someone gave me a "-1 vote"on my question, if I can't ask a simple question what this network it's made for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your data is in the JSON file.. Based on that I have updated the NotesShowController to [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) the `$http.get()` response and show the information on the Show view.

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GQy5qE5WjY1FXt1t1Gdw?p=preview):

NotesShowController:

```
angular
    .module('NotesApp')
    .controller('NotesShowController', ['$http', '$routeParams', function ($http, $routeParams) {
        var controller = this;
        controller.note = {};

        $http.get('notes.json').success(function (data) {
            controller.note = data.find(function (n) {
                return n.id === $routeParams.id;
            });
        });
    }]);
```

Show view:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <p>{{showController.note.title}}</p>
    <p>Created By: {{showController.note.users}}</p>

    <p>Description:</p>
    <p>{{showController.note.description}}</p>

    <p>Contents:</p>
    <p>{{showController.note.content}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: just one more question. Why Do I have to specify the controller name in the show.html file if I already defined it inside the route.js?

Comment: Your router file is configured to do so: `controller as showController`